# Can I save a bitmap in memory directly to Azure as a jpeg

Tags: c#, image, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to be able to resample a jpeg loaded into memory from the local network and then save the resulting bitmap file as a jpeg directly to the Azure cloud (without first having to save the jpeg to the local network then uploading).  I cannot find any methods for doing so, but I thought I would check here JIC.  Here's my high-level code, which is missing the part where the bitmap is saved to the blob as a jpeg:

```
Bitmap img = ImageMethods.ResampleImage(Image.FromFile(imageFileNames(i)), ImageMethods.ImageSize.Small_800x600)

var blobContainer = GetBlobContainer(Properties.Settings.Default.BlobContainerName);
var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobFilePath);

// Save image into Azure as jpeg...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `StreamWriter` using

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(blob.OpenWrite());
```

Then, you just need to save into this `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Am I able to save into the stream writer?  Do you mean this? ...  
                bitmap.Save(blob.OpenWrite(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);